# Post request on api endpoint does not return data

Tags: python, api, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently trying to use the API and the headers of a website instead of creating a web scraper. I have been trying to inspect the website by using Chrome Dev Tools and capturing the information under the `network` tab when an POST request has been made.

So far I have no luck and have only been getting `<Response [200]>` from the endpoint but no data returned.

Please advise what I did wrong.

Below is my Python code:

```
    import requests

    def get_data_from_api():
    search_keyword = 'money'
    api_endpoint = 'https://45bwzj1sgc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.2.0)%3B%20Browser'
    payload = {
        'x-xxxx-application-id': '45BWZJ1SGC', 
        'x-xxx-api-key': 'MTRkMGNlOGFhMWQ4YThmZDA0YmViNGY2M2ViYzBlMGMwNTBmMjllNjJmMDA4YmY1YzY3YzI2NzRmMzlhYThkM3RhZ0ZpbHRlcnM9JTVCJTVCJTIyc3VzX3B1YmxpYyUyMiUyQyUyMnN1c19jaGFubmVsX2FsbCUyMiUyQyUyMnN1c19jaGFubmVsX2ZlYXR1cmVkJTIyJTJDJTIyc3VzX2NoYW5uZWxfd2Vla2x5LW5ld3NsZXR0ZXIlMjIlMkMlMjJzdXNfY2hhbm5lbF9hbWElMjIlMkMlMjJzdXNfY2hhbm5lbF9saXZlc3RyZWFtJTIyJTJDJTIyc3VzX2NoYW5uZWxfc2hvdy1zdXMlMjIlMkMlMjJzdXNfY2hhbm5lbF9lbmdpbmVlcmluZyUyMiU1RCU1RCZhbmFseXRpY3NUYWdzPSU1QiUyMnN1cyUyMiU1RA=='
        }

    r = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers= payload, data=str(''' {"requests":[{"indexName":"OmniSearch_sus_production","query":"'''+search_keyword+'''","params":"attributesToSnippet=%5B%22body%3A80%22%2C%22searchable_comments%3A30%22%5D&page=0&hitsPerPage=10&filters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%5D%5D&facets=%5B%22channel%22%5D&sortFacetValuesBy=count&clickAnalytics=true"}]} ''')) 

    print(r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_data_from_api()
```

Comment: Pro tip: pass a dict, not a string, into `requests.post(data=...)` and let Requests serialize it for you. That's _way_ less error prone than manually writing out a dict as JSON.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Thank you for the tip!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, there are a few places where you can let Python do the hard work for you. Consider this alternative that uses `urllib.parse.urlencode` to create the `params` value, then lets Requests serialize your data structure:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests


def get_data_from_api():
    search_keyword = "money"
    api_endpoint = "..."
    headers = {
        "x-xxxx-application-id": "...",
        "x-xxx-api-key": "...",
    }

    params = {
        "attributesToSnippet": '["body:80","searchable_comments:30"]',
        "page": "0",
        "hitsPerPage": "10",
        "facetFilters": "[[]]",
        "filters": "",
        "facets": '["channel"]',
        "sortFacetValuesBy": "count",
        "clickAnalytics": "true",
    }

    r = requests.post(
        api_endpoint,
        headers=headers,
        data={
            "requests": [
                {
                    "indexName": "OmniSearch_sus_production",
                    "query": search_keyword,
                    "params": urlencode(params),
                }
            ]
        },
    )

    return r.json()
```

Quick, ApplePie! It's 2AM and something broke and everyone's in a panic! Which version of the code (which is functionally identical) would you rather have to troubleshoot?

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but take this in the spirit of "while we're on the subject...".

Answer (score 2):

You can have a try:

```
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 2):

the `r` is an [response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) object.
You can use

- `r.content` get the binary body.
- `r.text` get the string body
- `r.json()` or `orjson.loads(r.content)` get the json body

Check out more details by [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)